# The javascript,extjs calling function doesn't work when declare a function

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
<body>
<script>
Ext.onReady(function(){

   function update(){
    return  "<a class=update href='javascript:updateR()'></a>";
   }
   //problem block begins
   function updateR(){}          //1
   var updateR=function(){}      //2
   //problem  block ends
  In column set the header：renderer:update,//The code here calls the function update

}
</script>
</body>
```

The order of the 'code' above is the same to the real one.
  The problem is When I use 1 to declare a function,the browser says updateR is undefined,but when it comes to 2,it works well.
  I just can't understand why it works like this,hope for your help with much gratitude!

Comment: When you use JavaScript in the `href` like that (which is a bad practice), the function needs to be global.

Comment: Yeah,that is the point,I got the reason,thanks for your help.